# Attachment empty when shell script runs python module to make file and email

Tags: python, shell

My shell script runs a python task manager module that, at the end, makes a .png file. Then the shell script emails me the .png. If I run the tasks separately, they're fine, but combining them in the same .sh results in an email with an empty attachment.

Tail end of the python:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.scatter(goodRIDs.ASL75,goodRIDs.closet_count_per_slot, 
  color='green',alpha=0.2)
ax2.scatter(badRIDs.ASL75,badRIDs.closet_count_per_slot, 
  color='red',alpha=0.5)

plt.savefig('todaysASL'+str(pct)+'chart.png')

path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path+'/ASLgraphs')
plt.savefig(today+'ASL'+str(pct)+'vClosetperSlot.png')
```

And the shell script:

```
. venv/bin/activate


file=/home/todaysASL75chart.png
file1=/home/todaysASL95chart.png

python ~/WeeklyRIDTrendFinder.py 75 > $file
python ~/WeeklyRIDTrendFinder.py 95 > $file1


(echo "Today's ASL chart for the past week" ; uuencode $file ; uuencode $file1 )
 | mail -s "Weekly ASL Chart" -r "from@email.com" me@email.com
```

Is this some sort of flushing issue? I tried doing plt.flush(), but apparently plot modules don't act like files.

Comment: Tou may want to forget about emailing and shell scripts and provide a *minimal **working** example*,

Comment: Well, the python script works-- it does make a .png file. The shell script also works, when it just sends an email, rather than run and email. It's the combination with which I am struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a stdout vs. file save issue -- the shell script takes whatever python prints, and saves it at file and file1. Python, however, is saving the file and not printing anything, so the shell script collects nothing and saves it.

Changing the shell script to this:

```
. venv/bin/activate


python ~/monica-repo/dev/bi/RIDqualifier/WeeklyRIDTrendFinder.py 75
python ~/monica-repo/dev/bi/RIDqualifier/WeeklyRIDTrendFinder.py 95


(echo "ASL chart with the past week of RIDs at 48hrs") | mailx -s "Weekly ASL Chart" -a todaysASL75chart.png -a todaysASL95chart.png  me@email.com
```

Made it work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you need a delay between the chart creation and email creation? Maybe try a 2 second delay and see what happens. I have seen that solve issues in scripts before, might be worth trying.

Comment: Would you suggest the delay in the end of the python file or in the shell script?

Comment: I would of added it in the shell script but it looks like you found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `savefig` isn't closing the file correctly (and relying on the garbage collector). Try this:

```
#...
f=open(today+'ASL'+str(pct)+'vClosetperSlot.png', 'wb')
plt.savefig(f)
f.close()
#...
```